# Laravel Token in create

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I'm building a user management system...

when I create a user and put an image in 'avatar field' the user will create successfully

but when I let 'avatar field' empty he show me Token and the data that I insert in the field

I already put `@csrf` in my form

```
{
    "_token":"f8UnQweYC4xR6WahdsUDlFGoGxyuyzm61rpBEXXXX",
    "_method":"post",
    "email":"example@abc.xyz",
    "name":"example",
    "password":"123456789"
}
```

Store Method

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'name'         => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'          => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'          => 'required|string|min:8',
    ));
    $password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->roles()->detach();
    if ($request['user']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','User')->first());
    }
    if ($request['editor']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','Editor')->first());
    }
    if ($request['admin']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','Admin')->first());
    }
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/images/avatars/' . $filename ) );

    } else {
        return $request;
        $user->avatar = '';
    }
    $user->save();
    return view('content.admin.user.index');
}
```

Comment: because in your else you are returning `$request`

Answer (score 0):

as you are returning `$request` when there is no image uploaded , its returning you the entire data inside `$request`.

```
if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/images/avatars/' . $filename ) );

    } else {
        $user->avatar = '';
    }
```